# Need to stop execution of a method in Python 3.7 Version

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

On windows, I need to stop a python method execution after a specific time using Python 3.7 version. I tried with *multiprocessing.Process* but it is not able to call the method.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
def func1(name):
    print("Hi from func1")
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        print('hello', name)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=func1, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    p.terminate()
```

In the above code, it is not able to invoke the **func1** method. Please let me know if I am missing something or is there any better way to achieve this.

Comment: Everything works as it is on my side. Have you saved your file before running the script ?

Comment: You can't call the method? In that case, the  terminating part is irrelevant. I assume you don't see any of the prints. Are there any errors?

Comment: 1. Yes I have saved the file
2. I am not getting any errors and I don't see any print statements defined in the method. It will wait for 5 seconds then terminate.

Comment: code works correctly on Linux Mint. What system do you use?

Comment: I am using Windows and the python version is 3.7.10